# A subset that is not open

Tags: general-topology

how can I show that if $x$ and $y$ are two distinct points in a Hausdorff space with $U$ and $V$ the neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively, then $( U$ \ {$ x $} $)$  $\cup$  {$y$} is not open. Note that {$x$} and {$y$} are not open.
Ok I thought that if a contradiction arises then $x=y$. What I want to show is that if $X$ is a Hausdorff space such that any subset is either closed or open then there is at most one subset containing a single element that is not open.

Comment: you cannot show, unless you assume that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint (otherwise take $U$ to be the whole space).

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko I'm pretty sure that $U,V$ are assumed to be disjoint given that we have two distinct points along with two open sets in a Hausdorff space.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $(U \backslash \{ x\}) \cup \{ y\}$ is open. The intersection of two open sets must be open, so $$[(U \backslash \{ x\}) \cup \{ y\}] \cap V = \{y\}$$ must be open; an obvious contradiction.

Comment: Why look for an open set contained in $(U\setminus\{x\})\cup\{y\}$ when the assumption is already that $(U\setminus\{x\})\cup\{y\}$ itself is open?

Comment: Good point @HagenvonEitzen. That definitely reduces this to a one-liner.

Comment: Presumably you need some other restrictions or assumptions on your set. The discrete topology makes any space Hausdorff and this set would be open in that topology. Specifically the hidden assumption in this proof is that $\{y\}$ isn't open.

Comment: @Gage I thought all Hausdorff spaces are $\mathcal{T_1}$?

Comment: @graydad I don't think I follow. What definition are you using for $\mathcal{T}_1$?

Comment: There are two definitions that I am familiar with for $\mathcal{T_1}$ but one of them is that every singleton point is closed.

Comment: @graydad Being closed doesn't mean it can't also be open. Every set in the discrete topology is both open and closed.

Comment: @Gage ah good point. Then there are indeed extra assumptions needed for this proof to work. Luckily OP did say that singletons are not open

Comment: I totally missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.